# How to have a function feed another function's input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a hangman game and testing how different letter picking algorithms fare, but to do this, the guessing algorithm function has to feed a letter into the hangman function's `input('Select a letter')`.

How do you make it so that a function detects when another function is waiting for an input ?

Comment: You tagged with question with both `python-3.x` and `python-2.7`. Which version are you using? Are you aware that [Python 2 is officially deprecated](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)?

Comment: @Brian My bad I am using 3.6

Comment: One option is to run it as a subprocess and have the testing code pump newline delimited characters into its stdin. Another is to rewrite the hangman function to separate out the input prompt. That can get a bit tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are doing `input()` in a loop inside your hangman function, you could switch that to a `yield` and let an external function drive input as needed. In this example I have a hangman function that uses `yield` to get data. Now its a generator and driving function can use `next` and the generator's `.send` method to pump data into it.

```
def hangman(chances=5):
    for i in range(chances):
        letter = yield "prompt"
        if letter == "quit":
            yield "quit"
            return
        print("letter", letter)
        # do all the things
        solved = False
        if solved:
            yield "solved"
    yield "failed"

def command_line_prompt_hangman():
    feeder = hangman()
    state = next(feeder)
    while state == "prompt":
        state = feeder.send(input("Next letter: "))

def test():
    # after years of testing the best algorithm is
    test = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    feeder = hangman()
    assert next(feeder) == "prompt"
    for count, letter in enumerate(test, 1):
        state = feeder.send(letter)
        if state == "solved":
            print("did it in ", count, "tries")
            break
        if state == "failed":
            print("exceeded count")
            break

command_line_prompt_hangman()
test()
```

Comment: Being a rather casual user of Python I learned a lot of useful things from this, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `input` function, write a custom function to pull an output from whatever algorithm you are using.  That would look something like this:

```
user_input = algo_obj.get_input(game_state)
```

In this case, `algo_obj` would be an object storing the current state of the algorithm/generator (if such a state exists, otherwise you can just call the function normally).  `game_state` would be some representation of the game's current state (available letters, the word-form -- ie. blanks & letters).

You can then feed `user_input` to your Hangman function.

Comment: I have actually figured out the 'finding the next letter to pick from the current state of the game' part, I was looking for a way to make a function that starts the Hangman function and iteratively listens for an input() command, which would prompt it to feed it the best current choice for a letter, and wait for the next input prompt.

Comment: In that case, `input` should auto-wait whenever you call it.  Basically, you can just call the `input` function at the beginning of each cycle and either use it to check whether or not you should continue or just call and discard the result.  It will wait either way.

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as:

1. Define both functions.
2. Pass one function return value to the other one as argument.

This can be done by using `input()` as according to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp)

e.g. Define the functions

```py
def first_function():
    input_variable = input("Please enter some data")
    return input_variable

def second_function(a):
    print(a) # Do some calculations here
```

And use them:

```py
second_function(first_function())
```

I wouldn't say that this is necessarily the best way to go about but it solves Your problem. If You would like to receive a more detailed answer please provide code samples.